# How to make a projects from netbeans go live?

Tags: netbeans

I have been working on my website and I want to publish it on-line, but I have never done this before and its turning out to be more difficult than I thought, I was hoping it would be a case of dragging the folder over but no...

I recently subscribed to 1&1 but i dont think they are what I am looking for.

I have been coding in net beans and I want to be able to change my website about while its up.

Can anyone help??

Please ask if you have any questions!

Comment: It would be helpful to know the language you are programming in. Netbeans supports Java, PHP, Ruby, etc. So what have you used?

Comment: It is Just a small basic website, uses HTML and CSS at the moment planning on using some javascript and Jquery on it later...